# Grid Layout in Scroll View does not work well in iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a page which has a scroll view and a gridlayout in it. The problem is the grid is quit big and as the data are populated through a service I have kept the Height of each rows in the grid to AUTO. Now when the page loads and data gets populated the some portion of my gridlayout truncates from the bottom. It may be because my scroll view does not know the height of gridlayout in iOS.

**Anyone has any solution for this?** I'm still facing this problem.

Where as this works fine in Android devices.

Comment: Are you trying to display and populate a data grid? Similar to a spreadsheet in style?

Comment: Maybe try implementing it so that all the items don't load at once, and put in a "load more" button at the bottom?

Comment: @Marakai It is not that big, it is just a page where I show account details with their respective field names. There are 3 columns and about 22 rows.@PatrickGoode I don't require a load more option.

Comment: I saw a bug on bugzilla the issue is resolved there. But I'm still facing the problem.

Comment: @AkashAmin Ah, OK, I was asking because I got so tired with the iOS native grids, that I went with SyncFusion's DataGrid product and love it. They support every mobile os - Android, iOS, Windows, etc and I found it really powerful and easy to use. But the expense may not be worth it for you, if you're solution has limited needs.

Comment: I am using Xamarin Forms though.@Marakai

Answer (score 0):

Set `HeightRequest` of your `Grid` or set all `RowDefinitions` to constant size.

Comment: I can't do that, the server can return large data which might go upto 3 lines, so I have kept it auto.@Kowalski

Comment: Use StackLayout instead grid then.

Comment: I had stacklayout before, but that would decrease my performance.